# Server Principal SID showing as NULL and name as empty string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, audit, logins

In my SQL Server 2016 server,i set up a user logins Audit for Login successful and Login Failed action.
Here is the script.

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [ServerAuditSpecification-20190404-091348]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [Audit_SQL_Logins]
ADD (FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP),
ADD (SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN_GROUP)
WITH (STATE = ON)
GO



USE [master]
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT [Audit_SQL_Logins]
TO FILE 
(   FILEPATH = N'D:\SQL_Logins_Audit\'
    ,MAXSIZE = 20 MB
    ,MAX_FILES = 50
    ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
)
WITH
(   QUEUE_DELAY = 1000
    ,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE
    ,AUDIT_GUID = '77795756-1928-4ce4-85f5-e3ad2e3e22e5'
)
WHERE ([server_principal_name]<>'name1' AND [server_principal_name]<>'name2' AND ([server_principal_name]<>'name3' AND [server_principal_name]<>'name4') AND ([server_principal_name]<>'name5' AND [server_principal_name]<>'name6'))
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [Audit_SQL_Logins] WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

In the Audit Logs,

I can see lots of failures with Server Principal SID as NULL and name as empty string.Earlier when i set up the login i didn't give any filters and that time the Audit logs showed only success and there were no failures.

I don't understand what is getting failed here since the log shows NULL .

Additional Info:
[image]

Here is the screenshot.
This is a production database server and users are logging in from the .Net Web application.
I see the message "Network error code occurred while establishing a connection;the connection has been closed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the exact same audit and couldn't reproduce the problem you describe. When I log in with a login that doesn't actually exist:

> [image]

And for an intentionally wrong password:

> [image]

I even tried a name with a huge number of leading spaces and tabs, just to see if the name would get truncated and *look* blank, but leading whitespace gets trimmed.

Of course I would expect SID to be null in the first case, because what SID would you want to show for a login that doesn't exist (and therefore can't have a SID)? And for the second case, perhaps because a login couldn't authenticate, a match to SID wasn't made?

You'll have to provide more info to determine why server principal name isn't being populated. What is the application name? What does the *statement* say? What is the client (IP address in the statement)? Can you ask that person what they're doing?

Comment: I see the message "Network error code occurred while establishing a connection;the connection has been closed."So may be connection has not been established and that is why i see NULL entry and empty string name.But there are no reports of users not being able to logging in to the web application.Wonder why this is happening.

Comment: Sounds like when a login can't be attempted because of a connection failure, yeah, you need to do more digging into *that* as opposed to worrying about the login name. Just because nobody is complaining doesn't mean it isn't happening. Could be an asynchronous process or a rogue user or a code fragment left behind or any number of things that wouldn't affect users or that they wouldn't notice happening.